Websocket optimization for real-time VueJs 3 app running on background tabs
I have a data-view web app implemented in VueJs 3, using composition API. The data comes from multiple points, identified by a integer, their Id.
In the app there is a page where the user is able to see the most recent measure for lots of different points (up to 1500 points in the same screen), where the value of these points is updated via Websocket connection. In the Websocket message there are only two values, the point Id and the new measure value.
When I receive a new message, I need to go through a list of all the points being displayed, to see if the point in the message is on the screen, and where, so I can update it to the user.
The main problem is that messages are received all the time (most points update every minute), and for every message I need to find its point to update their value. This gets even worse when the tab of the running app is in the background (the user is in another tab or in another window), because of the resource limitation most browsers do for background tabs.
Here is a snippet of my webSocket.onMessage function:
webSocket.onmessage = async function (msg) {
        var msgJson = JSON.parse(msg.data);
        for (var i in formattedData.value) {
            if (formattedData.value[i].id == msgJson.pointId) {
                formattedData.value[i].measureValue = msgJson.measureValue.toFixed(2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

It is important to note that formattedData is the reactive list that has the data being presented to the user, and because of client specifications, I need it on a specific order depending on the user selected filters.
With all this, I have a few questions:

Is there a better way to store this data so it would be faster to find which point I need to update?
Would it be beneficial to receive a batch of points in one singular message instead of one point per message (is it better to process one long message or multiple short messages)?
Is there a way to not limit the browser's resources when the app is in a background tab?


I’m voting to close this question because IMO this would be better suited on Code Review

No, @ControlAltDel: the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se].  Specifically, it's missing sufficient review context and would likely be closed for that reason. You could have pointed the asker at A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the purpose of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code is for (the question is always, "How can I improve this?").

Also, being "better" on some other site is never a close reason - close it if it's off-topic on this site and explain why.  A recommendation for a more suitable site is a nice gesture, but only if you're correct.

I don't think the performance hit of such an app is caused by the looping of  data list or incoming websocket messages. It's most likely caused by the work put into the update of the template after any change have been made to component data. The most common problem is the update of the whole list of template elements when you make change to a single list element.
I would recommend focusing on that firsthand. A good start are the official tips on performance profiling and optimization: Perfomance.
Other than profiling your app with the recommended tools to have a better understanding where the resources are going, one optimization that I would definitely do in this case is code splitting and memoization.
Namely, if your point snippets aren't already separate components, start with that. Then look closely what props is that component relying on and when are they updated: See Props stability.
Another good technique of controlling when exactly are the template elements updated is the use of v-memo directive (v-memo). With that (like with the props for a component) you have control of a specific template element update.
Ideally, after the first load, your page should not take more resources to update than a page having only one single element (the one that needs to be updated).
